# Show Google Maps & YouTube videos after Cookies got accepted

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am using this plugin on my WordPress website: https://wordpress.org/plugins/cookie-notice/ and I am pretty satisfied with it because it's easy to use and lightweight.

With the latest GDPR rulings it is now needed to hide Google Maps and YouTube videos or replace them with a placeholder image as long as the visitor doesn't accept the cookie consent. Unfortunately the plugin doesn't have such a functionality.

Has anyone a sample code or an idea on how to embedd Google Maps and YouTube videos like that? All plugins that have this functionality cost around 99 $ a year, which is a bit too much for only one map and one YouTube video on my homepage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure how farmiliar you are with Jquery but you could do something like this.

```
var cookiesAccepted = false;
```

Add 'media-blocks' class to all media you want to hide.
Set jquery to watch Cookies bar for accept click. When its clicked add a class that shows all your embedded media that you wanted to hide, eg:

```
$('#cookie-btn').on('click',function(){
  var cookiesAccepted = true;
  $('.media-blocks').addClass('show');

})
```

Just a guideline of how I'd do it.

Comment: Thank you! Would you use a class for the elements to show/hide or a WordPress shortcode? And would it be possible to adapt this code to show an image of a map/a youtube video as long as the cookie banner has not been accepted?

Comment: so the .media-blocks css would be
 `{display:none;}`
Or  `background:grey;`
 Whatever css you want to hide the media with until the show class is added
 `.media-blocks.show{display:block;}`